# Showing $\cos{\pi \frac{mx}{R}}\sin{ \pi\frac{nx}{R}}$ are orthogonal in $L^{2}([0,R])$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to show that $\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{R}x\right)$ and $\cos \left(\frac{m\pi}{R}x\right)$ are orthogonal using the trigonometric identity that $2\cos{mx}\sin{nx} = \sin((m+n)x) + \sin((m-n)x)$ on $L^{2}([0, R])$.

I could conclude this is true of the region of interest were $2\pi$-periodic, but since $\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{R}x\right)$ and $\cos \left(\frac{m\pi}{R}x\right)$ have period $2R$ and the interval of interest is half that length, how can I conclude that

$$\int_{0}^{R}\cos \left(\frac{m\pi}{R}x\right)\sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{R}x\right)dx = \frac{1}{2} \left( -\frac{R \cos{\frac{\pi (m+n)}{R}x}}{m+n} \big\vert_{0}^{R}  - \frac{R\cos{\frac{ \pi (m-n)}{R}}}{m-n} \big\vert_{0}^{R} \right) = 0 $$

**Summary:** since both functions of interest have period $2R$ and are being integrated over a region of length $R$, how can the integral be shown to be zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this is not true.  For instance, taking $R=\pi$ for simplicity, consider $n=1$ and $m=0$.  Then the integral is $\int_0^\pi \sin( x)\,dx$, which is the integral of a positive integrand and is definitely not 0 (in fact it is 2).

Comment: To be clear, does this mean they are not orthogonal in $L^{2}([0,R])$? We could need $[0,R]$ to be replaced by $[-R,R]$ for this to be true?

Comment: @christoph: Correct.

Comment: Hmm... Wouldn't that imply that it's meaningless to consider these trigonometric functions as a basis for $L^{2}([0,R])$? Cause that's what I've been learning, so maybe I'm overlooking something?

Comment: @christoph: Where did you see that claim?  It could be a mistake, or you may have misunderstood it somehow.

Comment: I've been studying the heat equation on $[0,R]$, which required the introduction of Fourier analysis. I've been referring to [this pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/heateqn.pdf).

EDIT: There's only mention that they're orthogonal on $[-R,R]$, but wouldn't we need orthogonality in order to consider Fourier series on $[0,R]$?

Comment: @christoph: I don't see in that document a claim that $\sin(n\pi x/R)$ and $\cos(m \pi x/R)$ are orthogonal in $L^2([0,R])$.  Example 4 only refers to the sine functions (cosine doesn't satisfy the Dirichlet boundary conditions) and Example 5 uses $[-R,R]$.

Comment: That's true. I have it written somewhere in my notes that they are orthogonal in this space, so I'm a bit confused. I'm guessing in $[0,R]$, we just have that either the sines or the cosines form an orthogonal basis?

Maybe I'll try to write a separate post later to provide more detail about my difficulties. I appreciate your help, thanks a lot.

Comment: @christoph: I think the most likely explanation is that you made a mistake in your notes :-)